# How to debug Propel ORM query?

Tags: orm, propel

How can I debug Propel ORM object query? This is a sample query:

```
$obj = TableNameQuery::create()
   ->filterBy('ColumnName')
   ->find();
```

Comment: There's not a lot to go on here. What is the problem with your query, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

For debuging propel orm query,     for example your code is `$obj = TableNameQuery::create() ->filterBy('ColumnName') ->find();`   Now you can write as to debug it.`$returnArr = array();

$obj = TableNameQuery::create()->filterBy('Columnname')->toString();
$returnArr['response']=$obj;
return $returnArr;`

that all. it will show the propel query. you can view it.

Comment: @surendramaurya, please mark as the answer if you're happy